# Getting into loop when trying to access two SharePoint 2013 web-apps configured to use ADFS

Tags: sharepoint-server, authentication, web-application, adfs, cookie

I've configured two SharePoint 2013 web applications to use ADFS for authentication.

https://myapp

https://myapp:12345

Everything works fine when I access one of these two web-apps. But when I try to access another I get endless redirection loop to ADFS. Seems like I can access only one web application at the same time. I tried to find the reason and discovered that browser is using the same FedAuth cookie for both sessions. I can't figure out why it is happening. What can I do to prevent looping?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably far too late, but here is my proposed answer. ADFS will use the same fedauth cookie for a signed in user, even if you configured two relying parties separately. That is because it creates one cookie per user, not per RP. So I'd make sure that both web apps use the same auth provider (ADFS). Also make sure that you pass though the correct claims identifier from ADFS. if you told SharePoint that the claims identifier is upn, then make sure you send the upn. you do this by setting up claims rules on the RP to pass through incoming claims. 
Finally, you might be getting an issue, not with the fedauth cookie but the sharepoint security token. Both web apps are using the same domain base. Always try to use unique FQDNs for your web apps. i.e. myapp1.somedomain.com and myapp2.somdomain.com. setting up DNS takes about 10 seconds and will reduce your headaches considerably. for SSL, make sure you either manually request a cert that has all relevant domains in the Subject Alternate Name (SAN) list or use a wildcard ssl. I've had issues with Server Name Identification and SharEPoint 2013 in the past and stay away from that.